# Android MVP testing methods that needs network operations

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, mvp

I'm testing my app using Junit and Mackito, testing methods is gone good so far but not with methods that need network operations, how to test them properly, so that the assert is called after fetching data from the backend?

Comment: mock the backend data. Don't actually contact the backend

Comment: but that is some logic in the backend and I need to verify is the results is good?

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should test your app, not server side logic. So just mock methods which do network calls.

But, if you want to test network layer of app itself, there is good way, which I recommend, to do that - [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/)

Simply saying it creates locally running webserver which response with predefined responses.

Answer (score 1):

Is not a good idea test methods that depend on network calls. 
Better test backend apart and mock it in client.

Anyways, if you want to wait for the data use: `Thread.sleep(Xms)` in test method after network call and before your asserts.

```
@Test
public void testcase() throws InterruptedException {
    // make actions and network call

    // Wait, for example 2 seconds. It depends a lot of connection
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // Then assert whatever you want
}
```

Comment: @Divers Like I said It depens A LOT of connection time and quality. But, are there any other reason for not to use it? Thank for your answer.

Comment: You answered on your question - it depends on network connection, as a result your test can failed just because of slow connection, which makes tests useless. Even if you want to test against real server (which is bad idea), just test it on JVM, and do network queries in synchronous way.